# Online Excel bring data from another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying use a formula in online excel just like google spreadsheet "importrange".
I have workbooks as "workbook1.xlsx", "workbook2.xlsx" etc... and same sheet name "Summary"
want to bring them into "main.xlsx".

I'm taking the link of any cell from workbook1 and formula looks like:

```
='https://xxx/xx/workbook1.xlsx]Summary'!$A$2
```

This formula is OK, it brings the data.

I'm trying to change this part:

```
'https://xxx/xx/workbook1.xlsx]Summary'
```

I want to put different workbook links into main.xlsx column B like:

```
'https://xxx/xx/workbook1.xlsx]Summary'
'https://xxx/xx/workbook2.xlsx]Summary'
'https://xxx/xx/workbook3.xlsx]Summary'
```

and update formula automatically like:

```
=B2&!$A$2
=B3&!$A$2
=B4&!$A$2
```

this one is not working.

is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `INDIRECT` yet?

Comment: I tried but I think I'm not using in the proper format, Even full link in indirect didn't work. if you have example I can try it

Comment: Afaik per `MS` documentations, `INDIRECT()` wont support, please read **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)** --> It stated there : `Note    External references are not supported in Excel Web App with INDIRECT()`

Comment: thanks Mahukh is there any suggestion from your side? how can I modify the link?

Comment: @ÇAğrıKeskin sorry there is no workaround seems like, if i get something i will update it